# How to store ndarrays of different shapes, but same shape[0] in pd.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have for example

```
a = np.zeros((5, 6, 7))
b = np.ones((5, 8, 9, 10))
```

and I want

```
df = pd.Dataframe()
df["a"] = a
df["b"] = b
```

I get

> AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager
>   shape

I expect the Df to have 2 columns, and 5 rows. When polling for

```
a_polled = df["a"]
b_polled = df["b"]
```

I expect

```
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(a, a_polled)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(b, b_polled)
```

to pass.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you expect 5 rows?

Comment: @rafaelc because a.shape[0] and b.shape[0] == 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how pandas dataframe is meant to work. Dataframes are, [by construction](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), 2-dimensional.

> Two-dimensional, size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data.

For N-dimensional data, use [`np.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)s (i.e. **n**-**d**imensional **arrays**).

It is possible to have many dimensions in a data frame, though it is very strongly not recommended to do so. The way to do it is to store multi-dimensional objects in each cell. However, since the library is not built to work with n-dim data, you lose all the perks that comes with it (i.e. there is no vectorization, no n-dimensional index matching, no n-dimensional merges etc).

Comment: looks like pandas is not the way to go then. However, numpy is also not good enough, as I lose the "database-like" functionality from pandas. Is there something that supports my use case?

Comment: What database-like operations do you need? It makes no sense to me to join these two arrays in a single big array. It is the analog to, in a 2-dimensional space, trying to join a matrix `2x5` and a `2x3` in a single matrix - you can't do that, unless you *pad* the smaller matrix with `NaN`s or zeroes to match the bigger matrix shape. If this is the case, `ndarrays` should work just fine - you'd just have to reshape `a` to be of `b`'s size

Comment: Things like groupby, I guess. It is hard for me to think of use cases right now, which makes it hard for me to explain. Why would one use pandas over numpy for numeric-only data anyway? it FEELS to me like the answer to this question is the answer to yours. Sorry I can't come u with something more concrete right now.

Comment: @Gulzar I think the root of your problem is that you still don't know what you want to do, and thus it's hard to find a solution for a non-well-defined problem. But let me sketch out some points for you.. (I) `groupby` can be done in multiple dimensions with `itertools.groupby`, so you might wanna take a look at that. (II) Why pandas? Because it's human-friendly, and because it wraps some functionalities of numpy without too much performance loss. For example, you have named-indexes (e.g. columns), which humans love ...

Comment: … imagine a data frame of stock prices, with columns “high”, “close”, “open”, “volume” and “previous day close”. Without column names, it’s almost investable to work with this data set. In addition, imagine you also want a TICKER present (i.e. the stock symbol, like AMZN for amazon). In a numpy array you can’t (or at least shouldn’t) have different dimensions with different `types`, but in pandas you can! And still can operate in a vectorized way for each separate column. Of course, there are many other points to be made, but in general for 2-D cases, pandas is preferred for humans

Comment: accepted+starred, you are correct and your explanation is, for me, enlightening